# Bayesian network using BNLEARN package in python

Tags: bayesian-networks, model-fitting

can we create a Bayesian network using **bnlearn** package in python for 7 continuous variables (if the variables are categorical I can create a BN model)? If so, can you please guide me to any reference or example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment [bnlearn](https://erdogant.github.io/bnlearn) can only be used for discrete/categorical
modeling. There are possibilities to model your data though. You can for example discretize your variables with domain/experts knowledge or maybe a more data-driven threshold. Lets say, if you have a temperature, you can mark temperature < 0 as freezing, and >0 as normal. Or many smaller categories.